# Scala compiler infers overly specific type with complex type parameter

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, higher-kinded-types

I'm writing an FRM, with the fields abstracted over `F[_]`.

```
trait Query[A]
case class Field[A](name: String)
case class DBTable[T[_[_]]](fields: T[Field]) extends Query[T[Field]]

// example table
case class PersonalInfo[F[_]](name: F[String], age: F[Int])
```

I want to perform query rewrites using recursion schemes, so I need to define a pattern functor,

```
trait QueryF[A, B]
case class DBTableF[T[_[_]], B](fields: T[Field]) extends QueryF[T[Field], B]
```

and then a `coalgebra` to lift the Query into it:

```
type Coalgebra[F[_], A] = A => F[A]

def coalg[A]: Coalgebra[QueryF[A, ?], Query[A]] = {
    case DBTable(fields) => DBTableF(fields)
}
```

This works, but defining an `algebra` to convert in the opposite direction does not:

```
type Algebra[F[_], A] = F[A] => A

def alg[A]: Algebra[QueryF[A, ?], Query[A]] = {
  case DBTableF(value) => DBTable[A](value)
}
```

the alg function throws a compiler error, saying `constructor of type controllers.thing.DBTableF[T,B] cannot be uniquely instantiated to expected type controllers.thing.QueryF[?,controllers.thing.Query[?]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this here:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Query[A]
case class Field[A](name: String)
case class DBTable[T[_[_]]](fields: T[Field]) extends Query[T[Field]]

trait QueryF[A, B]
case class DBTableF[T[_[_]], B](fields: T[Field]) extends QueryF[T[Field], B]

type Coalgebra[F[_], A] = A => F[A]

def coalg[A]: Coalgebra[({ type L[X] = QueryF[A, X]})#L, Query[A]] = {
    case DBTable(fields) => DBTableF(fields)
}

type Algebra[F[_], A] = F[A] => A

def alg[A]: Algebra[({ type L[X] = QueryF[A, X]})#L, Query[A]] = {
  case dbtf: DBTableF[t, b] => DBTable(dbtf.fields)
}
```

or alternatively, with the last `case` replaced by:

```
  case dbtf: DBTableF[t, b] => DBTable[t](dbtf.fields)
```

if this is a bit clearer.

Both variants compile with `-Ypartial-unification` on 2.12.6.